# how to save multiple data in database from dynamic added textbox in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

How do I save multiple data from dynamically added textbox via javascript? I have done the dynamically added textbox for product list and payment terms. What should I do for the controller and View

I have test [This](http://demo.dotnetawesome.com/mvc/insert-multiple-record-to-database-at-a-time-aspnet-mvc4) but didn't work

here is my controller

```
 public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "PurchaseInvoiceTable,PurchaseInvoiceDetailsTable,PaymentTerm")]InvoiceWrapper model)            
{
    try
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            db.PurchaseInvoiceTables.Add(model.PurchaseInvoiceTable);                    
            db.SaveChanges();

            var PID = model.PurchaseInvoiceTable.PurchaseInvoiceID;
            model.PurchaseInvoiceDetailsTable.InvoiceID = PID;
            model.PaymentTerm.InvoiceID = PID;

            db.PurchaseInvoiceDetailsTables.Add(model.PurchaseInvoiceDetailsTable);
            db.PaymentTerms.Add(model.PaymentTerm);
            db.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        ViewBag.InvoiceID = new SelectList(db.PurchaseInvoiceTables, "PurchaseInvoiceID", "PurID", model.PurchaseInvoiceDetailsTable.InvoiceID);
        ViewBag.InvoiceID = new SelectList(db.PurchaseInvoiceTables, "PurchaseInvoiceID", "PurID", model.PaymentTerm.InvoiceID);             
        return View(model);
    }
    catch (DbEntityValidationException e)
    {
        //catch validation here
    }

}
```

Here is my invoiceWrapper

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace OnlineInvoiceSystem.Models
{
    public class InvoiceWrapper
    {
        public PurchaseInvoiceTable PurchaseInvoiceTable { get; set; }
        public PurchaseInvoiceDetailsTable PurchaseInvoiceDetailsTable { get; set; }
        public PaymentTerm PaymentTerm { get; set; }
    }
}
```

here is my javascript [You can test it on Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/va672kky/)

my view is this

```
@model OnlineInvoiceSystem.Models.InvoiceWrapper 

@{ Layout = null; Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml"; } 

@using (Html.BeginForm()) { 

@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<form>

  @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

  <h2>Product List</h2>

  <div class="panel panel-default product_wrapper">

    //dynamic added textbox will appear here

  </div>



  <button class="add_field_button btn btn-primary pull-right">Add More Fields</button>

  <div class="wrapper-payment-details">

    <tr style="background-color:black; color:white;" class="payment_term_wrapper">

      // here is the dynamic added payment terms textbox

    </tr>

  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <div>
      <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" /> @Html.ActionLink("Back", "Index", null, new { @class = "btn btn-small btn-danger pull-right", @style = "margin-right:2%;" })
    </div>
  </div>

</form>
  }
```

Comment: Refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28019793/submit-same-partial-view-called-multiple-times-data-to-controller/28081308#28081308) for some options

Comment: @StephenMuecke The [The Begin Collection is suitable for all MVC version? ] (https://github.com/danludwig/BeginCollectionItem) currently i was using MVC 5

Comment: Yes it works with MVC-5

Answer (score 0):

You should Model 
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PurchaseInvoiceID, new {id="PurchaseInvoiceID" ,@class = "form-control" })
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.InvoiceID , new {id="InvoiceID " ,@class = "form-control" })
then pass this variable through ajax or post json

Comment: can be more specific? i no understand

Comment: For refrence This is my Model class

Comment: public partial class Student
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> Standard { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> Marks { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> Dob { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
    }

Comment: This is my Controller

Comment: public JsonResult GetStudent()
        {
          
            var res1 = db.Students.ToList();
            var x = from d in res1 select new { Id=d.Id,Name=d.Name,Marks=d.Marks,Standard=d.Standard,Dob=d.Dob,
                Age = (today - d.Dob.Value.Year)


            };
         
           

            JsonResult res = new JsonResult();
            res.JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet;
            res.Data = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(x);
            return res;

Comment: Sorry For adding student controller is here

Comment: public JsonResult AddStudent(Student st)    {           
                Student s = new Student()   {
                    Name = st.Name,
                    Standard = st.Standard,
                    Marks = st.Marks,
                    Dob=st.Dob
                };
                db.Students.Add(s);
                db.SaveChanges();           
        }

Comment: This is my Add View

Comment: <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new
               {
                   htmlAttributes = new
                   { @class = "form-control" }
               })
                    </div>

Comment: This is my save.js file with ajax

Comment: $('#Save').click(function (e) {
            var student = { Name: $("#Name").val(), Standard: $("#Standard").val(), Marks: $("#Marks").val(),Dob:$("#Dob").val() };
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Result/AddStudent",
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',

                success: function (data) {
                    loadStudentList();
                },
                data: student
            });



        });

Answer (score -1):

You should use a javascript ajax (POST call), with a json containing all of your dynamic added fields (as a list maybe of item value objects), and on server side you need an action method that can process the list, you can't do it directly from MVC.

Comment: Post a solution then

Comment: I have given a link in the comments to the question:)

Comment: It requires a special Helper which is not in the MVC package:)

Comment: There are 2 options in the answer